# Measuring 'spread' of values between groups of observations

Tags: r

this is probably a fairly elementary statistics question, for something I will be implementing in R.

I want to measure the "spread" of test scores, both between individuals and between groups (e.g. to see which test question has the greatest disparity of results). I know I can use standard deviations to compare the spread among individuals, but what about between groups? Is it best to first take the average score for each group, and then measure the standard deviation of these averages?

To provide a concrete example:

Say I am collecting test scores for 9 people (p1 to p9), each belonging to one of three groups (g1 to g3). Three test scores will be collected (metric1, metric2 and metric3).

Here is some sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)
my_df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
      person = c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5",
                 "p6", "p7", "p8", "p9"),
       group = c("g1", "g1", "g1", "g2", "g2", "g2",
                 "g3", "g3", "g3"),
      metric1 = c(34, 43, 9, 70, 95, 81, 70, 33, 49),
      metric2 = c(38, 83, 81, 53, 20, 41, 89, 65, 41),
      metric3 = c(39, 87, 76, 88, 35, 85, 63, 29, 54)
)
```

For individuals, I know I can measure the spread of scores using standard deviation; for example:

```
my_df %>% summarise(
  sd1 = sd(metric1), 
  sd2 = sd(metric2), 
  sd3 = sd(metric3)
  )
```

What would be the best way to measure the spread between groups? Would it be to first take the average of  each group, and then measure the standard deviation of these averages? Intuitively this makes sense, but I wonder if I'd somehow be 'losing information' available at the individual observation level by first taking the group averages.

Grateful for any views you may have.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `summarise_at`

```
library(dplyr)
my_df %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(starts_with('metric')), sd)
```

If we need to do this by 'group'

```
my_df %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(starts_with('metric')), sd)
```